# Лысая башка, дай пирожка - what does it mean?

Tags: значения, идиомы, saying

Лысая башка, дай пирожка - what does this saying mean? I know what it means literally, but in which situations would it usually be used, and where/how did it originate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Лысая башка, дай пирожка» is a children's taunting ditty, a teasing rhyme used to make fun of bald people. There's an urban legend saying this rhyme originated in the early 20th century Odesa, now Ukraine, where there was a bald man selling patties (пирожки) downtown, so children composed the rhyme and used it when buying patties from him.

Answer (score 2):

It's a children's teasing chant (*дразнилка*). It's used to tease bald people.

> - Их девочка вдруг толкнула Соню в бок и прошепелявила:
>   — Лысая башка — дай пирожка!
>   — Лысая, потому что Настя уходила бродяжничать, потом всех заразила вшами, лишаями… ужас!
> - За столом, наложив в миски пурпурного винегрета, сидели двое мужчин, старик и просто мужчина, бритые и смешные. «Лысая башка, дай пирожка», — мысленно похулиганила Юлдуз.
> - А помнишь, как за глаза дразнил нашего естественника: «Лысая башка, дай кусочек пирожка»!